# How to wire subwoofer to 2.0 channel amplifier

Tags: amplifier, lm386

How to wire the sub-woofer amp to existing 2 channel amplifier?

I have dual LM386 for left and right channel and I would like to connect a sub-woofer.
where should I wire the sub ?

Is it in the right channel or the left channel and before LM386 or after or combine both channel ? (The sub will be use different IC and power source)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsgWDh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Using USB power for a subwoofer? No way, no how. Subwoofers take way too much power.

Comment: Aji, your question is a little difficult to understand. Could you perhaps edit it to include a circuit diagram? Then we may be able to reopen and answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mix channels at line level and then amplify each of them with individual amplifier.

Take a look at this article to get some ideas on how to mix audio channels: https://sound-au.com/project18.htm

Comment: if i do the hafler matrix will the right and left channel combine?